# How to integrate bunyan logs with google cloud stackdriver

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, bunyan

My app is hosted in gcloud app engine and generates bunyan logs. I'm looking for guidance to ship those logs to stackdriver and leverage stackdriver capabilities monitoring, logging and dashboards.. appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If bunyan is configured to write to stdout, we'll automatically pick those up and send them to Stackdriver Logging.  So this should mostly work :)  We're actively working on building a bunyan stream to help here, but stdout will work just fine.

On integrating with other services like monitoring - you need to find "Monitoring" in the Cloud developer console to walk through setting that up.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, [there is a `bunyan streamer` that supports this](https://github.com/mlazarov/bunyan-stackdriver).  It uses the `google stackdriver agent` under the hood.It nests the `bunyan` payload under a key of `structPayload` in `stackdriver`.

It works outside of `Google Cloud`, too, using a `service account` credential.